# How to deal with circular relationship in Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I'm trying to write a basic DB to offer my photographs. It seemed so simple, but I just can't wrap my head around this, despite thinking for a couple of weeks. I'm trying to combine multiple models that link to each other.

Photo: Files with some stored data
Person: Data about a person that appears in a photo / has mad a Quote

Quote: Something a Person has said and needs to be attached to Photos 
(the quote does not belong to all photos of that person, but rather a specific set)

Offer: An overview that has all the quotes with one Photo as a thumbnail and all the Photos 
(some photos might have the same quote, but it should only appear once)

As a mockup and because people here really love to see some code first I made this:

```
class Quote:
    person = models.ForeignKey("Person")
    photos = models.ManyToManyField("Photo")
    
class Person:
    photo = models.ForeignKey("Photo")
    
class Photo:
    pass
    
class Offer:
    quotes = models.ManyToManyField("Quote")
    photos = models.ManyToManyField("Photo")
```

Please take the code above as an illustration, because I already don't know how to tackle this. I tried multiple different versions, but there is always some case that doesn't get covered. In the above example the problem is: Person and Quote are independently attached to Photos. But there can't be a Quote without that Person being in there. So some information is doubled and might disagree. I also tried to using "through=" to bring People and Quotes together, but then ran into other problems.

Can you recommend any good tutorials or give me a hint how to deal with these kind of 'messy' relationships?

Thank you,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got things right. Following is a diagram showing how I would set up this class structure.

- **Person:** each person has multiple quotes and is part of multiple photos
- **Photo:** each photo is part of multiple photosets
- **Quote:** each quote references one photoset
- **Photoset_Photos:** many to many structure to connect multiple photosets with multiple photos
- **Photoset:** each photoset does include multiple photos and can be referenced by multiple quotes
- **Offer:** one offer references multiple photosets, with this reference you can get all quotes to their photosets and all photos

[image: class structure]